# How to make checkbox value non editable from inspect element

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I have two checkbox's  where 2 different value set to the checkbox.when a user checked the boxes value will be set. But before save it if he inspects the element and edit the value set a new value  and save into database instead of default value new value save into database.How do i stop doing that to the user..any possible suggestion?

```
<input name="installation" value="{{$product->installation}}" type="checkbox"> 

<input name="support" value="{{$product->support}}" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: How to stop someone using the browser inspector to change the state of a checkbox? You don't. You can use some `onchange`/`onclick` event which updates a flag for dirtiness. Or, if you don't want them editing the checkbox, don't have the checkbox.

Comment: The same should apply to any non-editable fields, this is something that penetration testing found lacking in a site I used to work on.  Values calculated by JS shouldn't be relied on and re-done in back end code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do not use the data from the `value` attribute of checkbox when working with the database.

For example, in controller, you can simply check whether the checkbox is checked, and then set any values you want:

```
$product->installation = ($request->has('installation')) ? 'checked' : 'not checked';
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you can add a client side or server side check that ensures that the value of the checkbox has not been tampered with

Comment: How would they go about doing that?

Comment: Well if you use a client side check, then you can add a validation function that is called when the form is submitted. The function can check if the value of the checkbox is within the range of acceptable values. If you use a server side check, then you can check if the value posted to the server is within the range of acceptable values